# I am trying to get my python twitter bot to tweet every 30 minutes on the hour. What should I do?

Tags: python, datetime, tweepy

The bot needs to tweet every 30 minutes on the hour (i.e at 12:30 and then 1:00 and then 1:30...). I understand tweepy and all of that. I just need to figure out how to get a timer working. I was thinking something like this:

```
if (time = "12:00") or (time = "12:30") or (time = "1:00") or...:
    # tweet
```

I don't know what package to use or how to set this up.

Comment: Is time actually a datetime object or is it a string of the time?

Comment: That attempt will fail right away. You cannot assign inside an `if` statement.

Comment: the code I provided is not actually in use. I'm just trying to the idea of what i'm trying to do make sense. I just need it to tweet IF time is on the 30 minute mark of the hour

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Could you show what you have been able to do so far? Did you search google for `python timer` or developed a code? Please, be more specific on what you need help with instead of "do this for me" kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using datetime you can actually get the minutes like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now()

minutes = time.minute
```

Or in one line:

```
from datetime import datetime

minutes = datetime.now().minute
```

Now that you have the minutes, the if statement can be simplified down, because you don't look at the hour.

```
if minutes == 0 or minutes == 30:
    # do tweet
```

EDIT:

You commented asking:
"Also curious, does that mean I need to run my program on the hour of :00 because the time is created through the now function?"

So theoretically here there are a few ways to answer this. Firts wrap your code in a function and call it constantly:

```
def tweet_check(minutes):
    minutes = datetime.now().minutes

    if minutes == 0 or minutes == 30:
        # do tweet

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This would be how it constantly runs the check
    while true:
        tweet_check()
```

## Option 1:

Then you can just manually run the script when ever you want your bot to be tweeting every 30 minutes.

## Option 2

With the check if **main** == '**main**' you will be able to import this script to another one and then run it on your own terms. As an imported script you can go the route of using the scheduler to run it at specific times.

## Option 3:

Run it as a system scheduled task (windows) or a cron job (linux) to have it run on boot.

However it's key to point out that if you do use it as option 2 or 3, it's probably best to modify it where you can pass in an optional variable if you want it to just send no matter the time.

So I would modify it like so:

```
def tweet_check(time_check=True):
    if time_check:
        minutes = datetime.now().minutes

        if minutes == 0 or minutes == 30:
            # do tweet

    else:
        # do tweet
```

This is because option 2 and 3 both inherently have timing built into them. So it would be excessive/inefficient to do it again here. In this simple example, that won't make much of a difference, but at the scale of say a few thousand tweets, that would end up rolling into the next minute and then would cut off some of the tweets.

Comment: Exactly what I was going for. Thanks!

Comment: @parisosuch can you mark this as accepted if it helped?

Comment: Also curious, does that mean I need to run my program on the hour of :00 because the ```time``` is created through the now function?

Comment: I'll edit my post and address your comment. It's going to be a little long for a comment response.

Comment: Thanks! I believed what I wrote works as well (check post edit). I ran it on an online IDE to test the functionality of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start [here](https://dev.to/bhupesh/a-simple-scheduler-in-python-49di) with **Scheduler** library. Try this as example of how it works, you can obviously do that natively but that's not recommended:

```
import schedule  

def job():  
    print("A Simple Python Scheduler.")  

# run the function job() every 30 minutes  
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(job)  

while True:  
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Answer (score -1):

I would look into the PyPI schedule module:

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/